# SQLServerException: "The result set is closed" when using Streams as return type

Tags: sql-server, java-8, spring-data-jpa

When trying to [stream results](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler#java-8-streams-in-repository-methods) from Microsoft SQL Server 2014 I always get an `SQLServerException: The result set is closed`. Also tried with `selectMethod=cursor` in the JDBC URL to no avail. Is there something MSSQL specific to consider? Using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE, Spring Data JPA 1.10.2.RELEASE.

Sample repository interface:

```
package sample;

import sample.Contact;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, String> {

    Stream<Contact> findByContactid(String contactid);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. If I switch to just a List<?> instead of a Stream<?> everything works (but in a slower, less memory-efficient way).

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution to this. I ended up using something like paging if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that making the service method that is calling the repository be inside of a transaction gets rid of this error for me.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<Results> myServiceMethod() {
    return repo.findByContactid("12345").map(c->c.getName()).collect(toList());
}
```